# How to maximize scalar product under constrains?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I have a multidimensional unitary vector $\vec n$. I need to find another unitary vector $\vec r$ which maximizes the scalar product:
\begin{equation}
(\vec r, \vec n) = r_1 \cdot n_1 + r_2 \cdot n_2 + \dots r_k \cdot n_k
\end{equation}
Obviously, without constrains $\vec r$ should be equal to $\vec n$. However, I have two types of constrains.

First, every component has an (component-specific) upper and lower bound:
\begin{equation}
l_i \geq r_i \geq u_i
\end{equation}

Second, there are several (overlapping) groups of components for which sum of components should sum up to 1. For example:

\begin{align}
r_1 + r_7 + r_9 + r_{11} = 1 \\
r_3 + r_7 + r_9 + r_{12} = 1
\end{align}

How can I find my vector $\vec r$. This is not a homework. I need to solve this problem since I run a gradient based constrained optimization. Vector $\vec n$ is my gradient.

Comment: @Korf, I guess that the difference with the linear program is that my vector should be unitary. So, it looks like a quadratic constrain (sum of squares of its components should be equal to 1).

Comment: @Roman you can somehow by-pass quadratic by putting $\bf r \cdot \bf n = \cos \alpha = c$ and adding the constrain $ -1 \le c \le 1$ as indicated in my answer

Comment: suppose you intend $-1 \le l_i \le r_i \le u_i \le 1$

Comment: @Roman Thanks, I missed that, deleting the original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The set of equations $r_{k_1}+r_{k_2} + \cdots =1$ plus the $\bf r \cdot \bf n = \cos \alpha$ represent a set of hyperplanes.
Their intersection will lead to express $r_k$ , unless degenerations, as a linear combination of $\lambda _1 , \lambda _2 , \cdots \lambda _m$ and
$c = \cos \alpha$.

Then you are left with a set of constrains for linear combinations of $\lambda _k $ and $c$,  including $-1 \le c \le 1$,
to maximize for $c$.

Comment: What are $\lambda_i$ and $m$ in $\lambda_m$?

Comment: @Korf : you  solve $ q $ equations in $q < n$ unknowns in terms of $n-q$ independent variables (call them $\lambda$), so actually read the above as $ \lambda _1 , \cdots , \lambda_{m=n-q}$